# how to limit the jquery mobile content and button width?

Tags: jquery-mobile, width, viewport

[image]
Try to limit the width of the buttons and content to no avail. Tried for 1 hour all the classes nothing seems to work..

I mean the space between the white buttons on the left and right side, towards the black. This space is about 10px But want to minimize it. anyone knows how?

.ui-page seems the way to go but also does not work.

Comment: you might want to take a look at [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904899/override-jquery-mobile-css)...

Comment: It looks like the padding from .ui-body, but difficult to tell without the html to fiddle with.