# CSS Style doesnt work how i need

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is, on start my page I don't want my gallery displayed, until the user clicks the button.

I think there's something wrong in my CSS, because i cant only open the background but the image doesn't show. In my opinion its something with "display". i have tried a lot of things but i can't fix my problem.

Thanks for any help.

CSS:

```
.fixed-bar{margin-top:43px;display:none}
.ui-btn-right{margin-right:70px}

.elastislide-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
}

.no-js .elastislide-list {
    display: block;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li {
    min-width: 60px; /* minimum width of the image (min width + border) */
    }

.elastislide-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 90px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.elastislide-wrapper.elastislide-loading {
    background-image: url(../elastislide/loading.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.elastislide-horizontal {
    padding: 10px 40px;
}

.elastislide-vertical {
    padding: 40px 10px;
}

.elastislide-carousel {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px);
    -o-transform: translateX(0px);
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.elastislide-horizontal ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li {
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.elastislide-horizontal ul li {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.elastislide-vertical ul li {
    display: block;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.elastislide-carousel ul li a img {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid white;
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* Navigation Arrows */

.elastislide-wrapper nav span {
    position: absolute;
    background: #ddd url(../elastislide/nav.png) no-repeat 4px 3px;
    width: 23px;
    height: 23px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.elastislide-wrapper nav span:hover {
    opacity: 1.0
}

.elastislide-horizontal nav span {
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top: -11px;
}

.elastislide-vertical nav span {
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    background-position: -17px 5px;
}

.elastislide-horizontal nav span.elastislide-next {
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
    background-position: 4px -17px;
}

.elastislide-vertical nav span.elastislide-next {
    bottom: 10px;
    top: auto;
    background-position: -17px -18px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container demo-3">
  <div class="main">
     <div class="fixed-bar">
         <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list" >
        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/1.jpg" alt="image01" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/2.jpg" alt="image02" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="elastislide/small/3.jpg" alt="image03" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixed-bar{margin-top:43px;display:block;}
```

The problem exists because there is no visible button in your code to activate the invisible parts with the use of  target selector.
Check this interesting example.
http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/wsD9L/

Comment: mhh.. when i start the page , the gallery still open automatic, but i want only when the user click on the button to open it

Comment: in jsfiddle works fine.. maybe the problem are the libraries i use?   http://jsfiddle.net/XfRWx/

Comment: for jquery mobile which libraries i have to use?

Comment: really don't know, check links such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904899/override-jquery-mobile-css

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though it should work since you have .fixed-bar  set to display: none.  That should make all of its children not show up.   Is it possible to have you get this working in a JSFiddle?  That would help everyone trying to answer it and also it might help you fix it in the process (always happens to me when it appears to be something small).

Comment: in jsfiddle works fine.. maybe the problem are the libraries i use?   http://jsfiddle.net/XfRWx/

Comment: Well if you can get it working in the jsfiddle then I'm pretty sure you can look at the fiddle and compare it to what you are doing locally to get it to work properly.  Since the jsFiddle is supposed to be a representation of what you have been working on locally.