# Overriding jquery mobile css

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a `table` which in the `header` I have to `align` the text to `center`.

```
.info-header {
   font-size: small;
   text-align: center;
}
```

However the `row` will still take the left `alignment` from **jQuery** mobile. Anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **jQuery** [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change it like:

```
$('.your-selector-class').css('text-align', 'center');
```

[**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904899/override-jquery-mobile-css?rq=1) can also may help you.

Comment: thank you! I managed to get a workabout with the links you've provided.