# Is there any way to highlight just ui-icon when active instead of whole button? *jQuery Mobile Related*

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a footer and navbar with a couple buttons. Each button has icons and text. I want the icon and text to highlight when active/selected instead of the whole button highlighting. Is this possible in jQuery Mobile?

Example Code Below:

https://jsbin.com/vefahejali/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How do you want it to look exactly? What do you mean by "highlight"?

Comment: So right now when you click on a tab the whole button turns blue. I just want the icon and text to turn blue. Hope that makes more sense

Comment: Use CSS to change the active state, so instead of the button having a colour when .active (or whichever class is used), do something like: .active .icon { styles}

Comment: You can override the jQuery mobile CSS, see another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904899/override-jquery-mobile-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the default jQuery CSS with these:

```
#pageone .ui-btn-active {
  background: inherit;
  color: #3388cc;
  border:none
}

#pageone .ui-btn-active:after {
  background-color: #3388cc;
}
```

**jsBin fork:** https://jsbin.com/fimiruyali/edit?html,css,output

---

**Output:**

[image: override jquery ui css]

Comment: thanks Aziz! This really helped alot. Last question is there a way to get the svg to appear blue? Like the actually image of the icon instead of the background color?

Comment: Nvm Aziz I have figured it out. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: How did you figure it out? AFAIK you cannot change a background image's color unless you do some hacky CSS filters or CSS masks. Otherwise can be resolved simply by using another blue image

Comment: Hi Aziz I just used another blue image like you suggested

Comment: Ok, you could change the SVG color by just changing the default white color (FFF) to your blue (3388cc) in the SVG data code. You'd have to do this for each icon. See jsBin: https://jsbin.com/qawuhamiri/3/edit?html,css,output